# Exception automating Excel 2007 with Powershell when calling Workbooks.Add()

Tags: powershell, excel-2007

The following code throws an exception in Powershell V1 (Excel 2007):

```
$E = New-Object -COM "Excel.Application"
$E.Visible = $True
$wb = $E.Workbooks.Add() #<<<Exception here
```

The error says that the format might be old or that the type library is not valid (translated from Spanish). A similar script for Word works just fine.

Comment: Is the Add method one of those that takes large numbers of optional parameters? If that's the case, then you may have to supply Type.EmptyType or whatever it is. Look up how to call it from C# (which has no optional parameter support until v4.0).

Comment: In my experience, depending on the Office version there's no need to use the Missing type for optional parameters, but for instance Word 2007 does require that arguments be passed as [ref] in PS, as opposed to Office XP, for instance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adapted to Powershell from one of the solutions proposed in [MS Help and Support Article 320369](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;320369).

```
$ci = new-object system.globalization.cultureinfo "en-US"

$e = New-Object -COM "Excel.Application"
$e.Visible = $True
$e.UserControl= $True
$books = $e.Workbooks
$books.PSBase.GetType().InvokeMember( `
       "Add", `
       [system.reflection.bindingflags]::InvokeMethod, `
       $null, $books, $null, $ci)
```

From the same article:

> When you use one of these workarounds for a computer where the regional settings
>   do not match the current language version of Office, you should be familiar with
>   how Excel behaves and how Excel will interpret data that might be formatted for
>   a specific locale.

Answer (score 10):

Office interop assemblies seem to have this problem when the current culture is not en-US. The obvious workaround is to set the culture.

It's important to run the whole thing as a single command on the interactive console, since PowerShell V1 always creates a new thread for each command invocation.

```
PS C:\Users\jachymko> $e = new-object -com excel.application
PS C:\Users\jachymko> $e.workbooks.add()
Exception calling "Add" with "0" argument(s): "Old format or invalid type library. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80028018 (TYPE_E_INVDATAREAD))"
At line:1 char:17
+ $e.workbooks.add <<<< ()
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ComMethodTargetInvocation

PS C:\Users\jachymko> & {
>> [threading.thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = 'en-US'
>> $e = new-object -com excel.application
>> $e.workbooks.add()
>> $e.visible=1
>> }
>>
```

Comment: I'll give this a try later, but I thought PSV1 used one process and one thread only?...

Comment: PowerShell uses a single execution thread per runspace at one time, but the thread exits after each command and is started afresh for the next one. I believe this can be controlled in V2 using the hosting APIs (you can make it use the calling thread or recycle the dedicated thread between commands)

Comment: Your solution doesn't seem to work for me... I keep getting the same error.

Comment: Are you sure you are running it using the & { ... }? Can you try it from C#? It should be sufficient, as per http://support.microsoft.com/kb/320369

Comment: Yes, I checked and it actually changed the CultureInfo for the thread, but the Excel method kept failing. The other workaround mentioned in the MS article does work for me, though.

Answer (score 3):

I had this issue when trying to open a workbook. I added this line:

```
[threading.thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = 'en-US'
```